# Do two dependent variables have a functional relationship?

Tags: function, dependent-variable

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two **dependent** random variables (e.g. they are the elements of a bivariate normal distribution with $\rho\ne0$). Is it true that there always exists a function $f$ such that $f(X,Y)=0$?

If the statement is not generally true, are there any special cases?
Moreover, how the $f$ in question (if any) could be found, given the pdfs of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: No not always (excluding the trivial example) unless $\rho =\pm 1$, in which case there will be a function where $f(X,Y)=0$ with probability $1$

Comment: Trivially, yes: let $f$ be constantly zero.  If $f$ is nontrivial and differentiable almost everywhere, then Calculus teaches us that the set where $f(X,Y)=0$ is a union of one-dimensional manifolds: that is, the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is *degenerate.*  For bivariate Normal variables this occurs only when $\rho=\pm 1.$ You don't need to analyze the PDFs or know much at all about the bivariate Normal distribution to draw these conclusions, which are general.